# How do I install red5 server and java

Tags: 12.04, red5

How do I install red5 server and java on ubuntu server 12.04 for videowhisper plugins for wordpress 4.1.1? What are the commands step by step?

Answer (score 0):

### Install Java

I recommend Oracle over OpenJDK.
Download the corresponding *jdk-8u40-*-*.tar.gz* file from [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) link and manualy install or by these simple commands (Webupd8 ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Webupd8 ppa repository also providing a package to set environment variables.

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

### Install Red5

```
sudo apt-get install -y red5-server
```

### Start red5

```
service red5-server start
```

Make sure to install both in the same directory. Everything should be fine by now. Kudos!

Comment: I did the commands and I got red5 installed but i got This page is used to test the proper operation of the Red5 server after it has been installed. If you can read this page it means that the Red5 server installed at this site is working properly. 
    HTTP Status 404 - /vod/index.html  type Status report

message /vod/index.html

description The requested resource (/vod/index.html) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

Comment: I downloaded the  jdk-8u40--.tar.gz file how do I install it manualy?What are the commands to install it manualy

Comment: I don't know why it is not working. Refer to this post for manual installation : http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: Hi I had to sign up a new account :
Like I said I ran all of the commands and still get the apache 404 error even though I get the red5 is installed page.
Will these commands install it in the same directory?